# how to access groovy closure annotations?

Tags: groovy, annotations, closures

Say that in my groovy code i've declared an closure with some annotation like this:

```
@GET('/heartbeat')
def myClosure = { req, res ->
  res.end('OK')
}
```

so now in my code I would like to extract the `GET` annotation out of the closure so i could create some automatic mapping:

```
public void doSomething(Closure closure) {
  closure.class.getAnnotations() // does not contain the GET annotation...
}
```

How can i get it?

So the full code would be:

```
@GET('/heartbeat')
def myClosure = { req, res ->
  res.end('OK')
}

public void doSomething(Closure closure) {
  closure.class.getAnnotations() // does not contain the GET annotation...
}

doSomething(myClosure)
```

Comment: Is `myClosure` a Field, or a local variable?

Comment: I think we might be venturing into the realms of JSR-308 and Java 8.  Prior to that, I don't believe it was possible to get runtime annotation info on a local variable.  Saying that, I'm struggling to get a working example with Java 8 :-/

Comment: His example suggests that he wants to look at an argument to a method (in his case, the "closure" argument to the "doSomething" method) and interrogate that object and expect to discover annotations that are attached to variable reference which happens to point to that object.  That can't be made to work, even with Java 8 and JSR-308, can it?  I don't think it is possible.  There could be any number of variables (local variables and/or fields) which all point to that same object and all of those variables could have different sets of annotations.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t.  The annotation is associated with the field, not the value of the field.  The closure is the value of the field.  When you do something like closure.class.getAnnotations() you are asking for the annotations that are on the groovy.lang.Closure class, not the object which the “closure” variable there refers to.